# How to use the computed to filter the `ul` in Vue by the input?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to use the computed to realize It? When I input in the input the `ul` only show the `li` which inclue my input. For example, if I am inputting the Ad, then only show the  "Add some todos" `li`. And if I give up input, the ul will goback, all the `li` will show again.
   This is my code, and I use Vue.

```
div id="app">
<input v-model="newTodo" v-on:keyup.enter="addTodo">
<ul>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
        <span>{{ todo.text }}</span>
        <button v-on:click="removeTodo($index)">X</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            newTodo: '',
            todos: [
                {text: 'Add some todos'}
            ]
        },
        methods: {
            addTodo: function () {
                var text = this.newTodo.trim()
                if (text) {
                    this.todos.push({text: text})
                    this.newTodo = ''
                }
            },
            removeTodo: function (index) {
                this.todos.splice(index, 1)
            }
        }
    })
     </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a `computed` to do the filtering you want done.
Use the computed instead of `todos` in your `v-for`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    newTodo: '',
    todos: [{
      text: 'Add some todos'
    }]
  },
  computed: {
    filteredTodos: function() {
      const re = new RegExp(this.newTodo, 'i');
      return this.todos.filter((item) => re.test(item.text));
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addTodo: function() {
      var text = this.newTodo.trim()
      if (text) {
        this.todos.push({
          text: text
        })
        this.newTodo = ''
      }
    },
    removeTodo: function(index) {
      this.todos.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="newTodo" v-on:keyup.enter="addTodo">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="todo in filteredTodos">
      <span>{{ todo.text }}</span>
      <button v-on:click="removeTodo($index)">X</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```